# Is "my class" generally understood as "the class I'm attending" or "the class I'm teaching"?

Tags: expressions, ambiguity

Example:

> I refused her invitation to join her swimming class.

For a native English speaker, does it read as "I refused her invitation to join the swimming class she's attending" or "I refused her invitation to join the swimming class she's teaching"?

Comment: There's no difference. You might as well ask whether "my meeting" means the one I'm attending or the one I'm chairing. But we don't. In context, it's either obvious or it's not; but in either case it rarely matters.

Comment: @JohnLawler Or is *my company* the one I own or the one I work for? Possessives can imply all kinds of things. Some people will say *When I had my accident I was in hospital for a week*. But in what sense was the accident possessed by the person concerned?

Comment: You are introducing the idea that she may be teaching the class.  The language doesn't support this or other suppositions.  Maybe "my" means she organized it but is not a teacher.

Comment: The point is that "possessive" massively underspecifies the relation. _`X`'s `Y`_ simply says that `X` and `Y` are an ordered pair, and invites the addressee to guess at the nature of the ordering, from context. Or to disregard it as unimportant.

Comment: Interesting question.  The context (and answer) is sometimes obvious (e.g., preK-8 [though high school onward’s not always obvious] or in your example, if the invitation’s coming from someone with or without those orange floaties on their arms).  “Our class” is also used, but that would still require context (although I usually heard that plural notion coming from the Teacher: “Glad you could join “us” [in ‘our class’] today, Mr. Poule”). Regardless, unless Teacher/Student fraternization is strictly prohibited, the difference probably won’t matter very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A native English speaker would need some context to know which meaning is intended.

Comment: I agree. I vote to close this as a "needlessly spinning our wheels" question.  This was a comment he gave in another question he posted, "Strange, I thought this was a very dumb question. I'm amazed it got 5 votes and a question with 43."

Comment: I personally am not going to vote to close because he asked a well defined question and I answered it.

Comment: Ok, I understand that.  I'm just not sure the OP is really taking the question seriously.